# Assigning dictionary values with sub-keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a current dictionary `grade_lists` that has the student name as the key and a list of grades as the value pair

```
{'Dave':[100,95,95]}
```

I need to assign assignment names for the grade values in a new dictionary; in this case, `['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3']`

so that

```
new_dict['Dave']['Exam 2'] == 95
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a nested dict comprehension, using a `zip` to match up the assignment names and grade values.

```
grade_lists = {'Dave': [100, 95, 95]}
names = ['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3']
new_dict = {k: {n: g for n, g in zip(names, v)} for k, v in grade_lists.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'Dave': {'Exam 1': 100, 'Exam 2': 95, 'Exam 3': 95}}
```

Comment: Exactly my answer, but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

A short variant of @wjandrea's answer:

```
new_d = {k: {x: v for x, v in zip(lst, *d.values())} for k in d}
```

where `d` is your existing dictionary, `lst` is the list of exam names.

**Example**:

```
d = {'Dave':[100,95,95]}

lst = ['Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3']

new_d = {k: {x: v for x, v in zip(lst, *d.values())} for k in d}
# {'Dave': {'Exam 1': 100, 'Exam 2': 95, 'Exam 3': 95}}
```